# Ask the user whether he wants to add duplicate information?

Tags: c++

I'm coding this program that allows users to add information to a .txt students list. In case the information entered is exactly the same as one of the students in the list (same name, same date of birth, same address, same entrance year and same major), I want to program to ask the user whether he still wants to add that student to the list or not. Any idea how can I do that? Here's my code:

```
void StudentList:: Add_Student () {
    int new_pid, new_ent_year;
    string new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_major;
    cout << endl << "Enter student information:" << endl;
    cout << "Full name: "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin,new_fname);
    cout << "Date of birth: "; getline (cin,new_dob);
    cout << "Address: "; getline (cin,new_addr);
    cout << "Entrance year: "; cin >> new_ent_year;
    cout << "Major: "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin,new_major);
    new_pid = tail->Get_pid()+1;
    Student *p = new Student (new_pid, new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_ent_year, new_major);
    //  p->Show();
    AddTail (p);

    // write to file
    f.seekg(0, ios::end);
    f << endl << new_pid << ":" << new_fname << ":" << new_dob << ":" << new_addr << ":" << new_ent_year << ":" << new_major;

}
```

Comment: Since you already have a list of `Student` objects, simply loop through it looking for an existing `Student` with matching info. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Implement a `bool isExist(const Student*);` function, if it is `true`, ask user to add it to the list anyway, if `false` just add it.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a useful question for the repository. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a list of `Student` objects, so simply loop through it looking for an existing `Student` with matching info.

```
bool StudentList::Student_Exists(const string &fname, const string &dob, const string &addr, int ent_year, const string &major)
{
    // search the list of Student objects for matching values
    // and return true/false accordingly...
}

void StudentList::Add_Student()
{
    int new_pid, new_ent_year;
    string new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_major;
    cout << endl << "Enter student information:" << endl;
    cout << "Full name: "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin,new_fname);
    cout << "Date of birth: "; getline (cin,new_dob);
    cout << "Address: "; getline (cin,new_addr);
    cout << "Entrance year: "; cin >> new_ent_year;
    cout << "Major: "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin,new_major);

    if (Student_Exists(new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_ent_year, new_major))
    {
        string choice;
        cout << "That student already exists. Add anyway? [y/n] "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin, proceed);
        if ((choice != "y") && (choice != "Y"))
            return;
    }

    new_pid = tail->Get_pid()+1;
    Student *p = new Student (new_pid, new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_ent_year, new_major);
    //  p->Show();
    AddTail (p);

    // write to file
    f.seekg(0, ios::end);
    f << endl << new_pid << ":" << new_fname << ":" << new_dob << ":" << new_addr << ":" << new_ent_year << ":" << new_major;
}
```

Obviously, you would have to implement `Student_Exists()` to search the `Student` list for an existing entry that matches the specified critieria.  How you do that depends on how `StudentList` is actually keeping track of `Student` objects.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
// ...
bool duplicate = is_duplicate(new_pid, new_ent_year, new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_major); // call function to check for duplicate info
if (duplicate) {
    string proceed;
    cout << "That's a duplicate!  Proceed? [y/n] "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin, proceed);
    if (proceed != "y") {
        return;
    }
}
Student *p = new Student (new_pid, new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_ent_year, new_major);
// ...
```

Comment: The OP wants to prompt *ONLY IF* an existing `Student` with matching info already exists. That is the missing step.

Comment: The OP : *I want to program to ask the user whether he still wants to add that student to the list or not*

Comment: That is only half the requirement. What the OP **actually** said is: "*In case the information entered is **exactly the same as one of the students in the list** (same name, same date of birth, same address, same entrance year and same major), I want to program to ask the user whether he still wants to add that student to the list or not.*"